# iOS Flash Drive SCSI Inquiry

Tags: ios, serial-communication, external-accessory, mfi

We are trying to send a SCSI inquiry to a iOS Flash Drive. Connected via USB we can send the following inquiry command using libUsb and Java:

```
private byte[] getInquiryCommand(byte replyLength) {
    // Command Block Wrapper (CBW)
    ByteBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(31); // ATTENTION!!!! WE NEED EXACTLY 31 BYTES! See: http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbmassbulk_10.pdf
    outBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    outBuffer.putInt(0x43425355);                   // CBW Signature
    outBuffer.putInt(0x84752008);                   // CBW Tag ~ command identifier
    outBuffer.putInt((byte) 0x24);                  // CBW Data transfer length
    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x80);                     // CBW Flags (0x80 = Data IN)
    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x0);                      // CBW Lun
    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x6);                      // CBW CB Length

    // Inquiry Command
    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x12);         // operation code
    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x01);         // reserved, CmdDt, EVPD
    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x80);         // page code

    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x00);         // reserved (or allocation MSB)
    outBuffer.put((byte) replyLength);  // allocation (reply) length
    outBuffer.put((byte) 0x00);         // control

    return outBuffer.array();
}
```

For this we are wrapping the SCSI command into the USB protocol. No we want to do the same thing with Swift and iOS. The problem is that we aren't in contact with the hardware manufacturer and we aren't member of the MFI program. 
We tried to send the same request in swift to a flash drive connected to a IPhone. But of course this doesn’t work because we are using the USB protocol to wrap the SCSI command, but we need to use some Lightning protocol Layer(That's what we believe...) This is the Request:

```
func getInquiryCommand() -> [UInt8]{
    return [
    0x55,   // CBW Signature 1
    0x53,   // CBW Signature 2
    0x42,   // CBW Signature 3
    0x43,   // CBW Signature 4

    0x08,   // CBW Tag ~ command identifier 1
    0x20,   // CBW Tag ~ command identifier 2
    0x75,   // CBW Tag ~ command identifier 3
    0x84,   // CBW Tag ~ command identifier 4

    0x24,   // CBW Data transfer length
    0x0,    // CBW Data transfer length
    0x0,    // CBW Data transfer length
    0x0,    // CBW Data transfer length

    0x80,   // CBW Flags (0x80 = Data IN)
    0x0,    // CBW Lun
    0x6,    // CBW CB Length

    // Inquiry Command
    0x12,   // operation code
    0x01,   // reserved, CmdDt, EVPD
    0x80,   // page code

    0x00,   // reserved (or allocation MSB)
    127,    // allocation (reply) length
    0x00,   // control

    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    0x00,    // Auf 31 Bytes auffüllen
    ]
}
```

The protocol string for one of our devices is "com.allbond.protocol05".

Does anyone know if it's even possible to send a SCSI inquiry this way?
We would also appreciate any further information to the topic.

Comment: did you find solution to this ?